# How to make a function that reads all colums of a single row of SQL Server and which output is the vector

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Hello Guys I'm noob into the VB.net and SQL world.

I would like to program a function which output is a vector that contains the values of the columns of the selected row.

I want to make a public function whose input is a query

For this particular example my query is:

```vb
"Select idcliente, Name, Lastname, from Clients where Celphone = '" + txtcelphone.Text + "'"
```

```
Public Function RunQuery_read_row(Query As String)    
    Try        
        Dim SQLCmd As New SqlCommand(Query, SQLcon)

        return  'The return should be a vector whose size will be adapted according to the query"
    Catch ex As Exception        
    End Try

End Function
```

This function will be called from a form that has a few textbox where the results of the function will be written down.

Thanks for the help

Best regards,
FBello

Comment: You're asking how to create an array or collection without knowing the number of items beforehand, which is something that you can easily find out for yourself.

Comment: When you say you want to output a vector, what exactly do you mean?  Do you want to output a generic list (type `System.Collections.Generic.List`).

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very unwise to concatenate strings for execution in Sql Server. Besides the fact that it is difficult to get all the single quotes and such correct, it can damage your database by Sql injection. Always use Parameters. I had to guess at the datatype and size of the parameter in the .Add method. Check your database for the correct values.

I have just passed the value of the parameter to the Function. Functions need a return type. Since I didn't know what you meant by a "vector", I used a DataTable.

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. Using...End Using blocks do this for you even if there is and error.

```
Public Class DataAccess
    Private Shared conStr As String = "Your connection string"
    Public Shared Function GetClientByPhone(phone As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New SqlConnection(conStr),
                cmd As New SqlCommand("Select idcliente, Name, Lastname from Clients where Celphone = @Phone", cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = phone
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
End Class
```

In the Form...

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = DataAccess.GetClientByPhone(TextBox1.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    TextBox2.Text = dt(0)(0).ToString
    TextBox3.Text = dt(0)(1).ToString
    TextBox4.Text = dt(0)(2).ToString
End Sub
```

I moved the Try...End Try to the Form code so a message box can be displayed to the user if there is an error. Don't write an empty Catch. Your code would swallow errors.

Comment: Woow! Let my try it. But I have a question
For example if I want to use another table instead of Clients, i want to use Bartender for example... I would need to change the code in the Public Cass DataAccess right?. Thank you bro!

Comment: Yes you will need to change the code. Write another Function for the difference table and different parameters.

Comment: Thank you bro! I think I'm getting the idea now. The code worked just flawless! :D